# How to find out what is wasting space on "/"?

Tags: disk-usage, aix

I can find out what is wasting space with this:

```
 du -sm * | sort +0nr | head -30
```

But what if "/" is filled 100%, and there are many mountpoints, ex.: /foo, /foo2, etc. How can I get a list of directory sizes in ex.: "/" that aren't mountpoints? (recursively not mountpoints?)

UPDATE: This doesn't work:

```
cd /; du -sxm * 2>/dev/null | sort +0nr | head -30
```

since it lists directories that are mounted in ex.: "/FOO" (tried this under: AIX6.1 and SLES 9.4)

UPDATE:

```
du -xm / | sort +0nr | head -30
```

this worked on AIX, now what? :D

Comment: Can you provide a list of /FOO w/ these mountings?

Comment: Can you also provide a `df -h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man du` itself mentions:

```
-x, --one-file-system
              skip directories on different file systems
```

so something on the lines of

```
du -xm * | sort +0nr | head -30
```

will do the trick, at least if you are using `du` from GNU coreutils (mine is version 8.20).

Not sure if that works with AIX (just noticed the tag after I posted the answer, sorry).

Comment: I updated the question with a suprise :O

Answer (score 3):

If something is wasting space and you can't find it, it may be hidden beneath other mountpoints. For example of you have a `/mnt/backup/` and made a backup while it wasn't mounted, the backup files will have ended up on `/`, but won't be visible anymore as long as `/mnt/backup/` is mounted later on.

The `--one-file-system` switch does not help there either; you have to make a clean unobstructed mount.

```
mkdir /mnt/something
mount /dev/yourroot /mnt/something
```

Then check `/mnt/something/` for files using `du`, `xdiskusage`, or whatever tools you like.

If that still doesn't yield anything, check for insane values of root reserve (for ext*, `tune2fs`), or check the filesystem in general (`fsck`) as some filesystem defects may cause used/free space to be calculated wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the [`-x`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds2/du.htm#du__row-d3e60805) option to `du` to avoid traversing other filesystems. Call `du` on the root directory itself (if you call `du -x *`, it traverses all filesystems whose mount point is immediately in the root directory).

```
du -mx / | sort -nr | head -n 30
```

Comment: Got: sort: field number is zero: invalid field specification `0nr'

Comment: @Totty Typo: that should have been `sort -k 1nr`. Or just `sort -nr` which is equivalent.

Comment: Ah, thanks (: I'm a noob in unix. Now it just hangs, it takes long time to show results?

Answer (score 1):

If there are lots of mountpoints, or files may have been written to a mountpoint before it was mounted, it is useful to mount the device on a secondary mount point.  On most systems I have worked with `/mnt` was available and unused.  Others actually use `/mnt` and place mount points for removable media there.  In either case you should be able to add a mount point there to mount the disk.  Mount the root device there and run `du` against that mountpoint.

To check for files that have been deleted but are still open compare the `df` usage to `du -k` for the mountpoint.  If you don't match the `du` blocksize the device blocksize, there will normally be differences.

Rotating log files without getting the logging program to reopen its log file can cause problems like this.  Many versions of `syslog` will reopen their log files when sent a `HUP` signal, others need to be restarted.